# Discord, sending a message to a different category and channel depending upon which reaction is selected

Tags: discord.js

I have been working on a way within my discord server to try to automate the flow of users who want to try out for a team using bots. Currently I have adopted YAGPDB and have a role menu created in a community level (category) #general_tryouts channel with reactions to specify which game they want to pursue. When they select a reaction they are assigned a temporary role (24 hours) which will grant them access to the game specific category #tryouts channel they've selected. I've been successful with getting all of the roles assigned using YAG's gui interface. However, I would also like for a message to be sent to the game specific #tryouts channel with an embed (similar to a welcome message) stating that they would like to tryout, to notify the 'team' that they are "in the queue". So the process would look something like this:

User A pops into (Some Community) #general-tryouts -> reads the menu asking them which team they want to tryout for and selects option 1 (':one:') -> User A is given the role for TempGame1 and can now see (Some Game) #tryouts AND simultaneously a message is sent to (Some Game) #tryouts on their behalf.

If they choose option 2 they will receive a TempGame2 role and a message should be sent to (Another Game) #tryouts.

If they choose option 3 they will receive a TempGame3 role and a message should be sent to (ThisOther Game) #tryouts.

YAGPDB has the option with it's custom commands to fire a command triggered by a reaction given in a certain channel by someone with a certain role. The issue is getting the result of which reaction they selected, and that dictating where the message is sent. I'm really not even concerned if it's just a generic message. I just want User A to be able to react at a 'community' level and a message to get passed in to (Some Game) #tryout, (Another Game) #tryouts, or (ThisOther Game) #tryouts based on their selection.

My apologies in advance. I am only proficient enough to code a simple I say "ping" you output "pong" sort of transaction, and got in a little over my head in short order. I have looked at the developer resources trying to piece something together to no avail, as well as pulling a similar snippet of code from here and attempting to modify it to suit my needs, also to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code Sample

```
if (reaction.message.id === '730000158745559122') {
    let channel = reaction.message.guild.channels.cache.get(targetChannelId);
    console.log(reaction.emoji)
    if (channel) {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setAuthor(
            user.tag,
            user.displayAvatarURL({
                dynamic: true,
                format: 'png',
            }),
        );
        embed.setDescription(`${user} has react a: ${reaction.emoji}`);
        channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

[Visual Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAjmM.png)

**New**

in the code `if (reaction.message.id === '730000158745559122')` the 73000 portion represents that whole message as a focal point on what the bot is 'listening' for. Any reaction to it, be it 1, 2, or 3 will trigger this singular process. So by what you are saying by using the (id === 123 || id === 456 || id === 789) {} would likely be the way to go if I had more than one message is was 'collecting' on for a lack of better way to state it. I believe what I need to do is

`if (reaction(':one:').message.id === 123 {send message ('nifty embed')to channel.id 12345}

if (reaction(':two:').message.id === 123 {send message ('nifty embed') to channel.id 67890}

if (reaction(':three:').message.id === 123 {send message ('nifty embed') to channel.id 16273}`

Comment: Can you show us the code you're having problems with?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code to it (using [codeblocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks))as it is much easier to read.

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti the sample has been uploaded. Thank you for your patience. As I said I am thinking that I need to split this one if statement into 3 separate statements. But if I am looking for a specific reaction of :one:, :two:, or :three:, the reaction.message.id === is just looking for any reaction to the message with that id right? How would I go about telling it to look for a specific reaction.message.id=== ?

Comment: You can do it like `if(x || y || z){}` in JS, where the `||` is the OR operator. (`&&` is AND). So in your case you could have `if(reaction.message.id === '123' || reaction.message.id === '456' || reaction.message.id === '789'){}` I hope this helps, sorry if I've misunderstood you!

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti  see above... I may not have explained it well so I will try to add a picture if it will allow me for visual reference.